# Variable constants in Doxygen

Tags: doxygen

I would like to document my code in a flexible way such that when something changes e.g. version, year (copyright), I do not need to make the changes manually in my >100 files.
My header looks like:

```
/** 
* \file main.cpp
* \copyright Copyright <2009-2014>
* \version 0.1
*/
```

2014 and 0.1 are two constants that will change constantly. Is there a way to define them somewhere in the project-file of Doxygen and automatically. **Is there any way to update these constants automatically?**

Comment: Did you have a look at the ALIAS possibility? e.g. ALIAS = "my_year=2015" and using \my_year in the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

As Albert suggested you can define an alias in the configuration file

```
ALIASES += thisyear=2014

/** 
 * \file main.cpp
 * \copyright Copyright <2009-\thisyear>
 * \version 0.1
 */
```

Alternatively, you can set THISYEAR as an environment variable and use

```
/** 
 * \file main.cpp
 * \copyright Copyright <2009-$(THISYEAR)>
 * \version 0.1
 */
```